# Android run service only when wi-fi is available

Tags: android, android-studio, service, android-service, android-networking

I am programming an app using Android studio. My app needs a service which every 3 hours downloads a file and cheks if there're new entries.
So, I've implemented my service:

```
public class MyService extends IntentService {

    public MyService() {
        super("My Service");
    }

    @Override
    protected void onHandleIntent(Intent workIntent) {

    //do something
    }
}
```

And in my main activity I started it:

```
startService(new Intent(this, MyService.class));
        Calendar cal = Calendar.getInstance();
        Intent intent = new Intent(this, MyService.class);
        PendingIntent pintent = PendingIntent
                .getService(this, 0, intent, 0);

        AlarmManager alarm = (AlarmManager) getSystemService(Context.ALARM_SERVICE);
        // Start service every 3 hours
        alarm.setRepeating(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP, cal.getTimeInMillis(),
                10800*1000, pintent);
```

As I said my service downloads one file, but I dont want to waste user's mobile data, so how do I make my service run only if wi-fi (unlimited data) available?
I've also created the class which checks network state:

```
public class ConnectionDetector {

    Context context;

    public ConnectionDetector(Context context) {

        this.context = context;
    }

    public boolean isConnected() {

        ConnectivityManager connectivity = (ConnectivityManager) context.getSystemService(Service.CONNECTIVITY_SERVICE);

        if ( connectivity != null) {

            NetworkInfo info = connectivity.getActiveNetworkInfo();

            if (info != null) {

                if (info.getState() == NetworkInfo.State.CONNECTED) {

                    return true;
                }
            }
        }

        return false;
    }
}
```

but I can't use it in my service (as my service runs not in main thread)
Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: You can use `JobScheduler` and define the constraints (when to run the job) with `JobInfo`. Take a look at [Scheduling Network Jobs on Unmetered Connections](https://developer.android.com/topic/performance/background-optimization.html#sched-jobs)

Comment: Why can't you use it in your `Service`? This method can be run on any thread.